# Is it still possible to access my App User's Friends with Facebook Graph API ? Is it deprecated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

very confused with the Facebook Developer documentation. There is a mention of user_friends having been deprecated back in April 2018, but unclear which interaction with a User's Friends is not allowed anymore.
In our case, we would like to allow the Users of our App to be able to check which of their Facebook Friends are already using our App. To connect to them in our App.

We can still find the below in the dev doc:
"
Facebook Friends

Due to privacy restrictions, you are only able to get a list of Users who have installed your app, not a complete Friend list. You can get a total count of all Friends which includes those who have not installed your app.

Edges

/user-id/friends
Access Token

User access token with user_friends permissions
Examples

Send a GET /id/friends request, where id is a user-id, to get a list of Friends who have installed the app and the total number of Friends.
"
With sample request below - can we still use the API that way ?

```
`curl -i -X GET \"https://graph.facebook.com/me
 ?fields=friends&access_token={your-user-access-token}"`
```

Any help understanding if the use above is still possible would be great. Thanks

Comment: Sure it is still possible - under the restrictions the documentation mentions, and which you just quoted yourself. Not sure what is unclear here?

Comment: @04FS Should have been more clear: here is the message on their website that got me confused: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

Comment: @04FS - with the message on that page: "User Friends - This edge has been deprecated as of April 4, 2018 and will return no data. Please see the changelog for more information."

Comment: I don’t think that note actually belongs on that page, this seems to be a mistake on Facebook’s end. Invitable Friends, Mutual Friends and Taggable friends are features that have been removed, and those are what the changelog is also listing in that position they are referring to. Friend _lists_ also only return empty data now, but accessing the friends of the app user that have also granted `user_friends` permission on their end – that still works fine.

Comment: Thanks @04FS for the input. This is actually in line with my own interpretation, but people around me understand it differently. I am therefore looking for a couple of real life cases of people who implemented access to the friends of the App's User in the last couple of month. Would you be one of them ?

Comment: I have not actually implemented much regarding Facebook APIs lately :-) - but a quick test in Graph API Explorer shows that it still works.

Comment: Again - thanks @04FS to the input and taking the time. Really appreciated. As you can tell from my question, this is all quite new to me. Actually - it seems like the API can be tested if I understand your last comment. I am going to try to reproduce that now with Graph API Explorer (assuming it is open access)...

Comment: Yes, it’s a test tool provided by Facebook, so that you can test basic API requests easily without having to write your own code at that point. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: There’s even some documentation on how to get started with it, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/explorer/

Comment: Perfect ! Let me try that, @04FS.

Comment: @04FS - managed to make it work. This is exactly what I was trying to confirm... thanks !